# Shell script for ploting multiple graph using gnuplot

Tags: shell, tcp, gnuplot

I am trying to analyze multiple tcp congestion control algorithm and for that trying to plot multiple graph but i am not able to make one comparative graph.

This is my script code:

```
gnuplot -persist <<"EOF"
set xlabel "time (seconds)"
set ylabel "Segments (cwnd, ssthresh)"
plot "./cubic.out" using 1:7 title "snd_cwnd cubic", \
 "./cubic.out" using 1:($8>=2147483647 ? 0 : $8) title "snd_ssthresh cubic",/
  "./reno.out" using 1:7 title "snd_cwnd reno", \
  "./reno.out" using 1:($8>=2147483647 ? 0 : $8) title "snd_ssthresh reno"
  ,/
EOF
```

But this script divides graph into two sub-section( both are not originating at origin)

Thanks

Comment: could you please provide a picture or the data and better explain what you would achieve

Comment: and some sample data

Comment: The forward slashes make your code incorrect. Continuation line breaks require backward slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Miguel advice, here is what you should try (remember to have `EOF` starting the line, any space before it would make it irrelevant):

```
gnuplot -persist <<"EOF"
set xlabel "time (seconds)"
set ylabel "Segments (cwnd, ssthresh)"
plot "./cubic.out" using 1:7 title "snd_cwnd cubic", \
 "./cubic.out" using 1:($8>=2147483647 ? 0 : $8) title "snd_ssthresh cubic", \
  "./reno.out" using 1:7 title "snd_cwnd reno", \
  "./reno.out" using 1:($8>=2147483647 ? 0 : $8) title "snd_ssthresh reno" , \
EOF
```